# Cleaning data in multiple columns and concatenating after

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe `dftest` which has these columns: `ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2,   ADDRESS3,   POSTCODE`. I'm trying to clean the data in each column and subsequently merge them into column `FULL ADDRESS` with a space between the data in each column.

This is what I'd like to do:
`replace(',', '').replace("'", '').replace('.', '').upper().strip()` but I can't figure out how to loop through the columns. Sometimes `ADDRESS2` and `ADDRESS3` have `NaN` entries given there is no data there, but when they do have values, I'd like them to be used in the merged final string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather the columns, using empty strings instead of NaNs:

```
parts = df[['ADDRESS1', 'ADDRESS2', 'ADDRESS3', 'POSTCODE']].replace(np.nan, '')
```

Concatenate strings:

```
full = parts.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Remove unwanted characters:

```
clean = full.str.replace("[,'.]", "").upper().strip()
```

And insert back into the dataframe:

```
df['FULL ADDRESS'] = clean
```